# _Prepend_ a new View to existing Scrollview-Views?

Tags: mobile, view, titanium, scrollview, appcelerator

Is there any option in Titanium Mobile Framework to *prepend* a view to existing views within a Scrollview? It seems that there's only the add-Method to *append* Views, but what i need is the possibility to *prepend* one.

Background: i want to be able to scroll any large Scrollview by adding a new View to the Scrollview when its scrolled to the right and prepent a new View to the Scrollview when its scrolled left. The existing View should then be dropped as soon as the new one is shown up...

Anyone has an idea how to achieve this?